# PyTorch: difference between type(a), a.type, a.type()

Tags: pytorch

suppose a is a tensor, then what's the difference between:

type(a)

a.type

a.type()

I couldn't find a document differentiating these.

Comment: additionally, what's the difference between float and tensor.float for the dtype?

Answer (score 3):

[`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) is the python in-built method.

- It will return type of object. like `<class 'torch.Tensor'>`

[`torch.Tensor.type`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.type) (`x.type()`) is pytorch in-built method.

- It will return type of data stored inside tensor. like `torch.DoubleTensor`, [etc.](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch-tensor)

---

Edit:

And about `x.type()` vs `x.type` -
When you write a function name with parentheses `x.type ()` it will actually execute the function and return its value. Whereas without parentheses `x.type` it is simply a reference to function.

Answer (score 2):

```
type(a) - returns the class type
a.type - returns built method type
a.type() - return the data type

>>> a = torch.Tensor()
>>> type(a)
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
>>> a.type
<built-in method type of Tensor object at 0x7f6a0acfc140>
>>> a.type()    
'torch.FloatTensor'
```